# sync multiple flows with ALM

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I have set up a Test with multiple Flows i.e Flow1 , Flow2, Flow3 and run the Flow but it takes only one flow.

> How can we sync multiple flows with ALM?

Answer (score 1):

Create a  flowmap.properties file in src folder and add the flow ids and path of the flow.xml file which we need to sync .

eg:

```
flow1=./sample_xml/flow.xml
flow2=./sample_xml/flow.xml
```

In run configuration, ALM sync-→Arguements

createTestCase flow_map flowmap(properties file name).